# How to solve the Deadlock of path guided agents in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, collision, anylogic, vehicle-routing

I am building a model that agents are path guided. The paths are one way. And there are several intersections.

But sometimes it encounters deadlock like this in the intersection point.

Deadlock image

[image: 1]

I have enabled collision resolve in the simulation model.But it doesn't solve the problem.

I also tried to reduce the min distance to obstacles too.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Collision resolution does solve the problem by temporarily turning off collision avoidance. Agents "squeeze" past each other. How does this not solve your problem? Or do you want it to work without this workaround?

Comment: I have enabled resolve collisions in the transporter control, and they should squeeze past each other. But still, they are stuck there, and agents cannot move. Why is this happening? Or what should I check?

Comment: might be too many in 1 spot. If 3 vehicles cannot move, only 2 might turn off collision avoidance for each other, but then they realize the 3rd vehicle and are stuck again. Maybe this causes an infinite loop of stuck... Hard to say, the library is a black box

Comment: Okay, that might be the issue. Thank you for your explanations!